# What is the difference between views that explicitly specify returned columns and those which do not (Teradata)?

Tags: view, teradata

I am working on an application which relies on Teradata objects meta information to perform some checks and tests. Using 'SHOW VIEW', I have noticed that views can be specified in two ways:

1) Explicit columns

```
REPLACE VIEW dw_v_customer
(
    col1, col2
)
AS LOCK ROW ACCESS
SELECT
     t1.col1, t2.col2
FROM table1 t1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 t2
```

2) No explicit columns

```
REPLACE VIEW dw_v_customer
AS LOCK ROW ACCESS
SELECT
     t1.col1, t2.col2
FROM table1 t1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 t2
```

**Question:** Is there a difference between these ways of creating/replacing views definitions?

Comment: No real difference. But the explicit column names in #1 overwrites aliases, e.g.  `REPLACE VIEW dw_v_customer
(
    foo
)
SELECT
     t1.col1 as bar` results in column name *foo*. If you want to parse the output you might consider using `SHOW IN XML VIEW` instead, this also includes the datatypes.

Comment: @dnoeth - so, columns in the parenthesis will be the final aliases. `SHOW IN XML VIEW` is very useful to find out data types, since `columnsv` seem to show them for tables (columns) only. I think your comment can become an answer to the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are identical. There is no difference. The first version is merely listing the columns and order explicitly.